# Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

like make regular Expression,

```
buy_towars_${item.towars}_press // item.towars => (3821731.mol) or (m*ilk)
```

```
/^buy_towars_(\w+)_press$/
```

I do this But it doesn't work

Comment: The things you show are not "words", which is what `\w` matches.  Why not just use `.*` in there?

Comment: instead of `\w+` use `[^_]+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match `(3821731.mol)` or `(m*ilk)` you have to escape the parenthesis to match them literally.

Note that `\w` does not match `*` or `.` so you can include that in a character class

```
^buy_towars_\([\w*.]+\)_press$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XZl4tm/1)

Or a very broad way to match could be using a negated character class matching any character except parenthesis:

```
^buy_towars_\([^()]*\)_press$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hhngO4/1)

```js
const regex = /^buy_towars_\([\w*.]+\)_press$/;

[{
    "towars": "(3821731.mol)"
  },
  {
    "towars": "(m*ilk)"
  }
].forEach(item =>
  console.log(regex.test(`buy_towars_${item.towars}_press`))
);
```